# How to add Callback function for delete operation?

Tags: 8, forms

I want to add a custom callback function for my delete operation.

```
$form['table'][$entity->id()] = [
        'title' => [
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#default_value' => $title,
        ],
        'status' => [
          '#type' => 'checkbox',
          '#default_value' => 1,
          '#disabled' => ($delta == 0),
        ],
        'weight' => [
          '#type' => 'weight',
          '#default_value' => $delta,
          '#attributes' => array('class' => array('mytable-order-weight')),
        ],
        'operations' => [
          '#type' => 'operations',
          '#links' => [
            'view' => [
              'title' => $this->t('View'),
              'url' => $entity->toUrl(),
            ],
            'edit' => [
              'title' => $this->t('Edit'),
              'url' => $entity->toUrl('edit-form'),
            ],
            'delete' => [
              'title' => $this->t('Delete'),
              // add callback function.
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ];
```

How do I do this?

What I tried so far was

```
'delete' => [
              'title' => $this->t('Delete'),
              '#callback' => 'myDeleteFunction'
            ],
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you are you looking for `$entity->toUrl('delete-form')`? But you might want to check first if `$entity->hasLinkTemplate('delete-form')`

Comment: No this delete Operation should not delete the entity it should delete a reference in a custom table, so I need a custom callback there.

Comment: there is no information about that in the question, you probably need to build the url from the route of the custom callback and fill the route parameters with entity data

Comment: "How to add Callback function for delete operation?" erm yes there is.
Hmm is there no other way? I don't want to make a page callback, just want to add a custom function for this operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operations are a list of links. If you want to delete a different entity see this example from the core workflows module how to build a delete link:

*WorkflowStateEditForm::Form()*

```
  $links['delete'] = [
    'title' => t('Delete'),
    'url' => Url::fromRoute('entity.workflow.delete_transition_form', [
      'workflow' => $workflow->id(),
      'workflow_transition' => $transition->id()
    ]),
  ];
```

Comment: You're right. I had to make a custom route with a custom controller to gain what I wanted to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As @4k4 said, operations are just  links. You can not have a callback on an operation. If you want to have just a callback, you need to make it a #type submit and display it separately from operations.

Otherwise you can make a route that does its thing and then redirects back to your list. Make sure to use a csrf_token then however, to protect against CSRF attacks.